# Running an Excel macro via Python? (New problem - saving)

Tags: python, excel, vba

I already saw this question in other link but I'm new here and i don't have reputation to comment there.

I made the script works and the macro run but when saving the file instead of just saving, it opens a excel pop-up asking if i confirm the changes. How do I save directly without opening this pop-up?

my code (edited):

```
import os.path
import win32com.client as wincl


if os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\peo_cpena\\Downloads\\excel.xlsx"):
    try:
        xl = wincl.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(
            "C:\\Users\\peo_cpena\\Downloads\\excel.xlsx"))
        xl.Application.Run("macro2.xlsm!Macro2")
        xl.Application.Workbooks("excel.xlsx").Save()
        xl.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        xl.Application.Workbooks("excel.xlsx").Quit(False)
        del xl
    except:
        xl.Application.Quit()
        print("It didn't work")
        del xl
```

Removing the Try i received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/peo_cpena/PycharmProjects/Cursoemvideo/UOL/CalculoImpARG.py", line 14, in <module>
    xl.Application.Workbooks("C:\\Users\\peo_cpena\\Downloads\\Vendas_por_Repasse_Aeria_Games_Europe_GmbH_01102020-31102020.xlsx").Save()
  File "C:\Users\peo_cpena\PycharmProjects\Cursoemvideo\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 197, in __call__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs),self._olerepr_.defaultDispatchName,None)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exceção.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)
```

Comment: It didn't work, continue opening the pup-up. I want to save in the same file which the macro runs.

Comment: In that case did you change the file name to "macro2.xlsm" ?

Comment: I have two files, one i have the macro that can be run in any workbook (macro2.xlsm) and the other I have the workbook that  I downloaded from the internet and is this that I want the modifications (excel.xlsx).

Comment: Which is line 14?  Plus I don't see where you open the file `macro2.xlsm`

Comment: Sorry.. Line 14 is  "xl.Application.Run("macro2.xlsm!Macro2")". In my script i use pandas (2 lines) to convert csv in xlsx but I don't think it interesting to put it here

Comment: I still don't see where you open the file "macro2.xlsm" - you can't run the macro if the file's not open.  I'm not a Python person so does `Dispatch` create a new Excel instance, or attach to an existing one?

Comment: Sincerely, i new with Python too and i found part of this script here. While I write the script I made some changes because I could not run macro, when I wrote like now, the macro ran inside excel even thought I was not "initializing". During the configuration of macro, I left the macro to run in all workbooks

Comment: Tim? Don't leave me alone haha

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out from your last comment exactly how you're opening `macro2.xlsm`   If you have code that does that, please add it to your post.  If not, then you need to write it in to your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly saving the workbook before closing it:

```
xl.Application.Workbooks("excel.xlsx").Save()
xl.Application.Workbooks("excel.xlsx").Close(False)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, i tried and didn't work too, the pop-up of excel continue opening and asking if I want to save the changes. =(

Comment: OK I've not seen that behavior before.  You can try adding `xl.Application.DisplyAlerts = False` before closing the workbooks.

Comment: Nothing... Continue opening the pop-up.. i don't know what else I can do =((((

Comment: `xl.Application.DisplayAlerts = False` sorry had a typo - don't know if you noticed

Comment: Yep, i saw and fix here but continue... I don't know if this what I want to do is really possible to do...